# argparse settings, set value after parsing

Tags: python, settings, argparse

I am thinking about using argparse as my source of truth for command line settings and reduce a lot of code this way.
For example, at the moment I am using separate variables to store the argparse arguments and also do some basic operations on them.

```
# Store product sets for upload, if argument is "all", take all options from available choices
args = parser.parse_args()
product_sets = args.product_sets
if "all" in product_sets: 
    product_sets = PRODUCT_SET_CHOICES[:-1]
```

Is it possible to do such a logical operation also directly on argparse?

Is it frowned upon to use argparse across the script rather than saving everything in a separate settings dict or variables?

Comment: `args` is a simple class object.  `args.product_sets = new_value` is allowed.  `print` `args` to see its 'content'.

Comment: Whether you pass the `args` namespace around, or individual attributes is entirely up to you.  It's a good idea to put the `parse_args` in  the `if __name__` block so it only runs when used as a script, and not when imported.  That way you can use easily use the functions in other modules.  So it's desirable to pass arguments in a way that's easy both ways.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, very good to know!